# Wordpress Custom Form Submission via admin-post.php stopped working

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I have a page with a custom form which sends post data via admin-post.php. This used to work fine a few days ago but now it seems that its not even triggering the function. Here is the code. **I also have some other similar forms on the same site but all of them have stopped working.**

```
<form action="<?php echo esc_url( admin_url('admin-post.php') ); ?>" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="create_user">
    <?php wp_nonce_field('create_user'); ?>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required/>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required/>
</form>
```

In my functions.php i have this

```
function create_user() {
    $retrieved_nonce = $_POST['_wpnonce'];
    if (!wp_verify_nonce($retrieved_nonce, 'create_user' ) ){
        $status = 'failed';
    }else{

      // My Code goes here
    }
}
add_action( 'admin_post_create_user', 'estudy_create_user' );
```

I have tried echoing something and dieing out the script just to check whether the function is being triggered or not but that too is not working.

Any help in the right direction would be great :)

Comment: admin_post only works for logged in users. Follow this guide: https://www.sitepoint.com/handling-post-requests-the-wordpress-way/

Comment: @TomBroucke Well i am logged in and have a custom role assigned. It used to work fine with this role.

Answer (score 4):

Well after some digging i found out that **admin-post.php** is used for admin side forms (which should have been obvious). While i was using it on the front end forms.

The solution for front end forms is quite similar, instead of **admin-post.php** use **admin-ajax.php**. Secondly replace `admin_post_*` hook with `wp_ajax_*` hook. And for frontend guest users use `wp_ajax_nopriv_*`.